# Ubuntu MATE 14.04 and suspend error

Tags: 14.04, suspend, battery, mate

I just installed Ubuntu MATE 14.04 on my computer 6 days ago, but have experienced that when I put it in suspend, it still empties the battery in a short time (the battery was half full, 4 hours, and went out during the 7 hour long night).

This morning I got an error message, saying Ubuntu 14.04 had experienced an internal error.

Here is the info from the error message:

```
ExecutablePath: /usr/share/apport/apportcheckresume
Package: linux-image-3.16.O33-generic3.16.O-33.44~14.04.1
Problemtype: KernelOops
Title: suspend/resume failure
Annotation: This occured during a previous suspend and prevented it from resuming properly
ApportVersion: 2.14.1-Oubuntu3.8
Architecture: amd64
InstallationMedia: UbuntuMate 14.04.2 "Trusty Tahr" - LTS amd64
InterpreterPath: /usr/bin/python3.4
PackageArcitecture: amd64
ProcCmdline: /user/bin/python3/usr/share/apport/apportcheckresume
ProcEnviron: TERM=linux, PATH=(custom, no user)
```

Some more, but they have a lot of info, and I don't think they are necessary.

I am pretty new with Ubuntu/Linux, but am trying to learn. I did some searching, but could only see others having trouble with the part of starting the computer again, while I think my problem is that it don't actually suspend or save the battery as it should.

Any thoughts what it can be/what I should check or do?

Comment: Abnyone else having any thoughts? It keep happening, and I don't know if I should find another OS or what I should do ...

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can do is to upload the information so that the problem can be fixed. That's what it's there for. The gathered information can be used by the system to find similar reports, which helps developers identify the cause. This service also knows what pieces of information could potentially be privacy sensitive and anonymizes it before making it available.

Reporting bugs is how software is improved. It's like calling customer care when you have an issue. It is also a good contribution to Ubuntu, because your report might lead to the problem getting fixed before other users encounters the same bug.

Comment: I did send the bugreport (as one of the buttons asked me to do). But I also hoped somebody else had experienced it, so that I maybe could get tips to a solution since it is a problem.